# Django aggregate min/max with other fields

Tags: django, aggregate-functions

I wounder, can I convert this sql:

```
SELECT MIN(price) min_price, * FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```

with Django ORM ?
I need one object from each month with minimum price. So I tried use aggregate():

```
Model.objects.filter(*filtering*).aggregate(Min('price'))
```

but it lost other fields, shows only 'price'
Tried, to post fields i needed:

```
Model.objects.values(*some fields*).filter(*filtering*).aggregate(Min('price'))
```

But after this i didn't get any field ! Even price.
So i need an object with min price and other fields too

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to use .order_by()?

For example:

```
YourModel.objects.all().order_by(min_price)[:1]
```

When you want to get the values of your model fields you can access them by using template tags like this `{{ YourModel.yourModelField }}`

And if you want to access them outside of templates you have to do it like

```
mymodel = YourModel.objects.all().order_by(min_price)[:1]
print(mymodel.yourModelField)
```

the print() is a example ofcourse

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't what i need.
I need one row in each month with minimum price. Your example will give me only one row...
You suggest me "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY min_price LIMIT 1;"
But I need:
"SELECT MIN(price) min_price, * FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date);"
As a result i must see many rows, but one row per month with min price in that month